# What is the best approach for dealing with RabbitMQ DLQ messages in Spring AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I am using Spring AMQP to listen RabbitMQ queue. While listening queue, depending on business logic, my service can throw RuntimeException and in this case message will retry several times. After max count retries, message will stay in DLQ. And I am wondering, what is the best approach to deal with these messages in DLQ? I read from blogs that I can use ParkingLot Queue. But also in this case, how to monitor the queue and notify people about dead-letter messages?
P.S. Sorry for my English. Hope that I was able to explain my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RabbitMQ REST api (Hop client) to get the status of the DLQ.

You can also use Spring's `RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties("my.dlq")` to get the message count.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#broker-configuration

Other options include adding another listener on the DLQ and run it periodically to either send it back to the original queue or send it to a parking lot queue if it fails too many times.

There's an example of that in the [spring cloud stream documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#rabbit-dlq-processing).